# How to get json.hpp to work in my c++ project on Mac

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to get `json.hpp` to work in my c++ project on my Mac computer.

These are the steps I took...

1. Create a c++ project with a `main.cpp` file
2. include this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"

using namespace std;
using jsonf = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
  jsonf jsonfile;

  jsonfile["foo"] = "bar";

  std::ofstream file("file.json");
  file << jsonfile;

  return 0;
}
```

3. went here [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to get the source code. I downloaded the zip file and decompressed it and added it to my project. I only added the file `nlohmann/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp` to my project directory. So only the `json.hpp` file. I did this because I saw somewhere online that I should do this. I forgot where though.
4. I compiled my `main.cpp` file and ran it and I get these errors...

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:
./json.hpp:129:6: warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
enum class value_t : std::uint8_t
     ^
./json.hpp:156:61: error: expected function body after function declarator
inline bool operator<(const value_t lhs, const value_t rhs) noexcept
                                                            ^
./json.hpp:2238:19: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<typename ...Ts> struct make_void
                  ^
./json.hpp:2240:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using type = void;
                 ^
./json.hpp:2242:19: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<typename ...Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
                  ^
./json.hpp:2242:41: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<typename ...Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
                                        ^
./json.hpp:2254:18: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    nonesuch() = delete;
                 ^
./json.hpp:2255:19: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
                  ^
./json.hpp:2256:33: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
                                ^
./json.hpp:2257:28: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&&) = delete;
                           ^
./json.hpp:2257:34: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&&) = delete;
                                 ^
./json.hpp:2258:39: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
                                      ^
./json.hpp:2259:28: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    void operator=(nonesuch&&) = delete;
                           ^
./json.hpp:2259:34: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    void operator=(nonesuch&&) = delete;
                                 ^
./json.hpp:2264:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
         template<class...> class Op,
                       ^
./json.hpp:2265:15: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
         class... Args>
              ^
./json.hpp:2268:21: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using value_t = std::false_type;
                    ^
./json.hpp:2269:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using type = Default;
                 ^
./json.hpp:2272:39: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                      ^
./json.hpp:2272:59: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                                          ^
./json.hpp:2273:43: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
struct detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...>
                                          ^~
                                          > >
./json.hpp:2275:21: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using value_t = std::true_type;
                    ^
./json.hpp:2276:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using type = Op<Args...>;
                 ^
./json.hpp:2279:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                       ^
./json.hpp:2279:44: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                           ^
./json.hpp:2280:21: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using is_detected = typename detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;
                    ^
./json.hpp:2282:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                       ^
./json.hpp:2282:44: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                           ^
./json.hpp:2285:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                       ^
./json.hpp:2285:44: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                           ^
./json.hpp:2286:20: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using detected_t = typename detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::type;
                   ^
./json.hpp:2288:39: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                      ^
./json.hpp:2288:59: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                                          ^
./json.hpp:2289:21: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using detected_or = detector<Default, void, Op, Args...>;
                    ^
./json.hpp:2291:39: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                      ^
./json.hpp:2291:59: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                                          ^
./json.hpp:2292:23: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using detected_or_t = typename detected_or<Default, Op, Args...>::type;
                      ^
./json.hpp:2294:40: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Expected, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                       ^
./json.hpp:2294:60: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class Expected, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                                           ^
./json.hpp:2295:27: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using is_detected_exact = std::is_same<Expected, detected_t<Op, Args...>>;
                          ^
./json.hpp:2295:72: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
using is_detected_exact = std::is_same<Expected, detected_t<Op, Args...>>;
                                                                       ^~
                                                                       > >
./json.hpp:2297:34: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class To, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                 ^
./json.hpp:2297:54: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template<class To, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                                                     ^
./json.hpp:2299:5: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    std::is_convertible<detected_t<Op, Args...>, To>;
    ^
./json.hpp:2729:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto pos = s.find(f);                // find first occurrence of f
         ^
./json.hpp:2779:34: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    std::size_t chars_read_total = 0;
                                 ^
./json.hpp:2781:41: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    std::size_t chars_read_current_line = 0;
                                        ^
./json.hpp:2783:28: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    std::size_t lines_read = 0;
                           ^
./json.hpp:2786:5: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
    constexpr operator size_t() const
    ^
./json.hpp:2812:17: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
    const char* what() const noexcept override
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:104:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char* what() const _NOEXCEPT;
                        ^
In file included from main.cpp:3:
./json.hpp:2812:29: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    const char* what() const noexcept override
                            ^
                            ;
./json.hpp:2822:48: error: member initializer 'id' does not name a non-static data member or base class
    exception(int id_, const char* what_arg) : id(id_), m(what_arg) {} // NOLINT(bugprone-throw-keyword-missing)
                                               ^~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2917:16: warning: generalized initializer lists are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        return {id_, pos.chars_read_total, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2917:16: error: non-aggregate type 'nlohmann::detail::parse_error' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        return {id_, pos.chars_read_total, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2926:16: warning: generalized initializer lists are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        return {id_, byte_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2926:16: error: non-aggregate type 'nlohmann::detail::parse_error' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        return {id_, byte_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2960:16: warning: generalized initializer lists are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2960:16: error: non-aggregate type 'nlohmann::detail::invalid_iterator' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2978:16: warning: generalized initializer lists are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2978:16: error: non-aggregate type 'nlohmann::detail::type_error' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2995:16: warning: generalized initializer lists are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:2995:16: error: non-aggregate type 'nlohmann::detail::out_of_range' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:3012:16: warning: generalized initializer lists are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:3012:16: error: non-aggregate type 'nlohmann::detail::other_error' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        return {id_, w.c_str()};
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./json.hpp:3041:19: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using uncvref_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
                  ^
./json.hpp:3055:21: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;
                    ^
./json.hpp:3081:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template <typename T, T... Ints>
                       ^
./json.hpp:3084:24: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using value_type = T;
                       ^
./json.hpp:3085:12: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept
           ^
./json.hpp:3085:27: error: non-friend class member 'size_t' cannot have a qualified name
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept
                     ~~~~~^
./json.hpp:3085:27: error: no member named 'size_t' in namespace 'std'
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept
                     ~~~~~^
./json.hpp:3085:33: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept
                                ^
                                ;
./json.hpp:3096:17: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template <size_t... Ints>
                ^
./json.hpp:3097:24: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using index_sequence = integer_sequence<size_t, Ints...>;
                       ^
./json.hpp:3106:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template <typename T, T... Ints, size_t SeqSize>
                       ^
./json.hpp:3109:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using type = integer_sequence < T, Ints..., (Ints + SeqSize)... >;
                 ^
./json.hpp:3112:24: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template <typename T, T... Ints, size_t SeqSize>
                       ^
./json.hpp:3115:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using type = integer_sequence < T, Ints..., (Ints + SeqSize)..., 2 * SeqSize >;
                 ^
./json.hpp:3124:9: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        typename Extend < typename Gen < T, N / 2 >::type, N / 2, N % 2 >::type;
        ^
./json.hpp:3130:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using type = integer_sequence<T>;
                 ^
./json.hpp:3143:31: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using make_integer_sequence = typename utility_internal::Gen<T, N>::type;
                              ^
./json.hpp:3151:29: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<size_t, N>;
                            ^
./json.hpp:3158:19: warning: variadic templates are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
template <typename... Ts>
                  ^
./json.hpp:3159:28: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using index_sequence_for = make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>;
                           ^
./json.hpp:3173:12: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
    static constexpr T value{};
           ^
./json.hpp:3173:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    static constexpr T value{};
                      ^
                      ;
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
67 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

I am not sure if my c++ version is not right but I tried checking my version doing the following `g++ --version` and `c++ --version` and in both cases got the same result...

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Would really like to get this working but I am not sure how.

Comment: It is very strange. The default C++ version in clang 12 is C++14. What compiler flags or shell aliases are you using?

Comment: It looks like the project is set up to use a c++ version older than c++11. So the problem is likely to be in this step `1. Create a c++ project with a main.cpp file`  or `4. I compiled my main.cpp file and ran it and I get these errors...` how do you compile it?

Comment: I compile it doing the following `g++ main.cpp -o main && "pathToMyExecutableMainFile"main` Where that path is `"/Users/myname/etc.../"`

Comment: What c++ version do I have I don't even see it?

Comment: You can choose it with compiler flags `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main`

Comment: I think Xcode has an option that can change the c++ version in the project description page: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350629/401352. Or you can directly add the `-std=c++11` in the command line:  `c++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`

Comment: Thanks @t.niese it worked

Comment: @273K for some reason Apple's clang is different and still defaults to c++98